# MongoDB Pool timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, connection, pool

I need some help analyzing a problem I am encountering during the last weeks.

Every here and then my application hangs. Basically it is based on postgres but for some very speedy interactions we transfer critical data into mongodb which is kept synced. This works out - its pretty fast and we do not habe problems keeping it synced.

We use java 1.6 and spring 3.2. I instantiate one Mongo-class and @Autowire it in about 15 business logic classes.

Now my problem is: After about 2 days I get exceptions:

```
com.mongodb.DBPortPool$ConnectionWaitTimeOut: Connection wait timeout after 120000 ms
    at com.mongodb.DBPortPool.get(DBPortPool.java:186)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:327)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:189)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result._advance(DBApiLayer.java:452)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result.hasNext(DBApiLayer.java:418)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:503)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:523)
```

I suppose, the pool is running out of connections.

Now my question:

Do I always have to call db.requestDone()?

According to this page:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Driver+Concurrency - first paragraph, I read:

> The Mongo object maintains an internal pool of connections to the
>   database (default pool size of 10). For every request to the DB (find,
>   insert, etc) the java thread will obtain a connection from the pool,
>   execute the operation, and release the connection.

To me this sounded like the connection is being passed back whenever the thread is closed, which should have happened after the request has finished.
We do not have any long-living threads in our app accessing mongodb.

Thanks for any hint!

Jan

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this problem when we failed to close our cursors after reading.  After adding a `cursor.close()`
after all our cursor operations, the  problem went away